# Borders Object in Excel 2010, pass by reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a formats encoder that grabs the format of a given range, and then provides the ability to paste that format on another given range (basically emulating "Paste Formats", but storable).   I'm trying to set the Borders object of a range (in the set routine), but it seems that a Borders Object is passed by value, and not reference?

I can get the current values of the Borders object just fine, but if I try to set any value to it, it's straight up ignored (without even an "Read only" error). Follows is a snippet of my code:

```
Sub SetBorders(sInput As String, ByRef Target As Borders)
Dim resultPart() As String
'Border indexes go from 5 to 12
For i = 5 To 12
    'Set resultPart
    resultPart = Split(Split(sInput, CharEOList)(i - 5), CharEORecord)
    If Len(resultPart(0)) > 0 Then
        Target(i).ColorIndex = CLng(resultPart(0))
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using a higher Range object and drilling down to the Borders object inside it?

Comment: Yes, it would be simpler to pass in the Range object instead of trying to pass the Borders. Maybe you could update your question to include how you're currently calling this sub?

Comment: It's an inner function of a larger routine, which is why the parameter is passed like that. It's called like so:

    Sub SetCellFormat(sh As Worksheet, theRange As Range, format As String)

...        If UBound(s) >= 3 Then If Len(s(3)) > 0 Then SetBorders s(3), theRange.Borders

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, access order is very important to the Borders object. I had been setting .LineStyle at the top, when it should have been more at the bottom. Setting LineStyle first (ie, to None), and then setting a Color, reverts the LineStyle to the one in the Borders Object.

Finished portion of that code:

```
Sub SetBorders(sInput As String, ByRef Target As Borders)
    Dim resultPart() As String
    'Border indexes go from 5 to 12
    For i = 5 To 12
        'Set resultPart
        resultPart = Split(Split(sInput, CharEOList)(i - 5), CharEORecord)
        'If index is empty, set that property to Variant/Null
        If Len(resultPart(0)) > 0 Then Target(i).ColorIndex = CLng(resultPart(0)) Else Target(i).ColorIndex = Null
        If Len(resultPart(1)) > 0 Then Target(i).color = CDbl(resultPart(1)) Else Target(i).color = Null
        If Len(resultPart(2)) > 0 Then Target(i).ThemeColor = CDbl(resultPart(2)) Else Target(i).ThemeColor = Null
        If Len(resultPart(3)) > 0 Then Target(i).TintAndShade = CDbl(resultPart(3)) Else Target(i).TintAndShade = Null
        'Weight and LineStyle seem to always be set
        Target(i).Weight = CLng(resultPart(4))
        Target(i).LineStyle = CLng(resultPart(5))
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next i

End Sub

Function GetBorders(b As Borders)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""
    Dim resultPart() As String
    'Border indexes go from 5 to 12
    For i = 5 To 12
        'Reset resultPart
        resultPart = Split(",,,,,", ",")
        'Skip errors. This will leave that index blank, which equates to a Null when using Borders
        On Error Resume Next
        resultPart(0) = b(i).ColorIndex
        resultPart(1) = b(i).color
        resultPart(2) = b(i).ThemeColor
        resultPart(3) = b(i).TintAndShade
        resultPart(4) = b(i).Weight
        resultPart(5) = b(i).LineStyle
        On Error GoTo 0
        Result = Result + Join(resultPart, CharEORecord) + CharEOList
    Next i
GetBorders = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (XL2010), so there must be some other issue going on with your code.

**EDIT** - I see you figured it out.

```
Sub tester()
    SetBorders Selection.Borders
End Sub


Sub SetBorders(obj As Borders)

    Dim arr, x

    arr = Array(xlEdgeBottom, xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeRight, xlEdgeTop)

    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        With obj(arr(x))
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, Excel tries to be ever so helpful if you only do one thing, but trying to set things en masse gets quite tricky, since it 'fixes' things every step of the way.